# Where to put a voltage (DC/DC) converter that must be switched on/off by the control signal?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, control

My device only has 5 V power supply, and this is difficult to change. I must operate another, smaller device that requires 12 V. I plan to use some DC/DC converter like TMA 0512D to produce the necessary voltage. The master device has enough power.

As the small device must receive 12 V only when required, it is possible to put the control circuitry before the converter (then the converter would stay disconnected most of the time, except few seconds per hour, and power is a concern) or put it after the converter (then the converter would run all the time but may produce less noise and transients). The main device is a small computer so it is important not to reset it by chance.

How would be usually done?

Comment: Hmm, I'd simply switch the 12V for the converter / device with a 5V relay?

Comment: try a schematic ; but I understand your need, yes you can drive a relay with a mosfet & few components to activate or not the DC/DC converter..

Comment: Can‘t you simply high-side-switch the converter?

Comment: A schematic would help anyway

Comment: A lot of DC-DC converters and controllers already have an enable line.  However, you need to be careful of their off characteristics--some disconnect the output, some force it to ground, some leak to/from the input.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis ... and some have EN pin internally pulled up to VIN, which might make it impossible to drive directly from main controller, especially for buck converters (hopefully not the case here).

Comment: @Maple, a FET would fix that, but OP indicated the input was 5V...with only that information, my best guess was that 5V was the processor supply.  He mentioned he "only has 5 V power supply," so it seems likely.

Comment: Unable to find PCB mounted 5 to 12  V 100 mA converter with enable line. Could you possibly tell?

Comment: @h22 Have you tried any standard sources? digikey, mouser etc? Pololu has [U3V50F12](https://www.pololu.com/product/2568) which is rather overkill, but fits the bill

Comment: No it does not fit any bill, I need a PCB mounted small component, not a large device on its own. The space in the enclosure is limited. Yeasterday I found that Triaco Power TDNN 1-1212WI has the needed voltages, power and "remote" as they write. It's only drawback, needs external components to stay RFC compliant.

Comment: Most DC-DC modules require external components to meet Class B. That's because inductors and caps for that often take as much space as module itself and not everyone needs certification.

Answer (score 1):

Even with a bit of unknown in your system spec requirements, here are my thoughts.

You mentioned 2 ways to control the load power rail:

1. On-off switch **upstream** the DC-DC converter (switching Vin)
2. On-off switch **downstream** the DC-DC converter (switching Vout)

I would add one more:

3. Controlling the DC-DC converter on-off state through a built-in *Enable* or *Shutdown* input

For #3, you most likely need to design your own DC-DC converter circuit choosing a part that has the enable/shutdown logic, it looks like this is not an option for your setup. In any case, this solution has many advantages like:

- not adding external control circuit
- re-using the soft-start feature to "gently" power-up the load (most DC-DC converters come with it)
- very-low quiescent current when shut down

For #1 and #2, you've already mentioned the pros and cons of both solutions so let me suggest a simple implementation :)

If you can integrate it into your circuit, high-side switching can be done using a combination of N-channel + P-channel MOSFETs that should work beautifully.
Have a look at this post:

[High Side Switch Implementation (Active-High)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/311156/high-side-switch-implementation-active-high/311199)

The "control" line would be wired to your 5V logic.

For the **upstream** option, wire the "5V-input" to your 5V rail and the "5V-Switched-Output" to the DC-DC converter Vin (voltage input). When "control" is high (eg. above the N-channel Vgs turn-on threshold, between 1 and 2.3V for this FET), the "5V-Switched-Output" will be connected to "5V-input" and feed the 5V rail to the DC-DC converter. When "control" is low, the "5V-Switched-Output" will be disconnected from the "5V-input" therefore the DC-DC converter will start to starve and its output (12V) will go down to ground.

For the **downstream** option, it will have the exact same logic except you would need to connect the "5V-input" to your DC-DC converter output (12V). The FETs used in this circuit will still work at 12V, both their Vds and Vgs can support up to 30V and 20V respectively.

Now there are a few things you should have in mind:

- however dependent of your 5V and 12V rail capacitance, the switching from on to off state (and vice-versa) will be quiet "quick" (in ms). If you need a graceful power shutdown, you should probably tell the 12V device to save its context before shutting it down (if in the middle of running operations, it may power back up in a confused state)
- it is true the upstream switch will prevent current draw from the DC-DC converter when turned off but we are talking micro-amperes and if your system can deal with that (eg. not battery-powered), there is nothing wrong putting the on-off switch downstream
- in the upstream implementation, I mentioned you would "starve" the DC-DC converter when the switch is off which will cause its regulation logic much trouble if the Vin under-voltage threshold is too low, it may compromise your DC-DC converter reliability
- the upstream switch will need to switch a higher current than the downstream switch as you have to account for the DC-DC efficiency. If your system sinks 500mA at 12V, the downstream switch can use FETs with lower currents. Now assuming your dc-dc converter efficiency is around 85%, the current on the 5V rail will be around 1.4 amps. If your system consumes even more power, you may end up having to cut-off 3-4 amps on the 5V, definitely keep this in mind when selecting the switching elements!